# Whats the difference between sed -E and sed -e

Tags: regex, linux, sed, debian

I'm working on some old code and I found that I used to use

```
sed -E 's/findText/replaceWith/g' #findText would contain a regex
```

but I now try

```
sed -e 's/findText/replaceWith/g'
```

It seems to do the same thing, or does it?
I kinda remember there being a reason I done it but I can't remember and doing "man sed" doesn't help as they don't have anything about -E only -e that doesn't make much sense ether.

```
-e, --expression=script
  Append the editing commands in script to the end of 
  the editing command script. script may contain more 
  than one newline separated command.
```

I thought -e meant it would match with a regex...

```
GNU sed version 4.2.1
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

From source code, `-E` is an undocumented option for compatibility with BSD sed.

```
/* Undocumented, for compatibility with BSD sed.  */
case 'E':
case 'r':
  if (extended_regexp_flags)
    usage(4);
  extended_regexp_flags = REG_EXTENDED;
  break;
```

And from [manual](http://www.ipnom.com/FreeBSD-Man-Pages/sed.1.html), `-E` in BSD sed is used to support extended regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

From [sed's documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Command_002dLine-Options):

> -E

> -r

> --regexp-extended

> Use extended regular expressions rather than basic regular expressions. Extended regexps are those that egrep accepts; they can be clearer because they usually have fewer backslashes. Historically this was a GNU extension, but the -E extension has since been added to the POSIX standard (http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=528), so use -E for portability. GNU sed has accepted -E as an undocumented option for years, and *BSD seds have accepted -E for years as well, but scripts that use -E might not port to other older systems. See Extended regular expressions.

Therefore it seems that `-E` should be the preferred way to declare that you are going to use (E)xtended regular expressions, rather than `-r`.

Instead, `-e` just specifies that what follows is the script that you want to execute with `sed` (something like `'s/bla/abl/g'`).

Always from the documentation:

> Without -e or -f options, sed uses the first non-option parameter as the script, and the following non-option parameters as input files.