# How to use sed to replace regex capture group?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a large file with many scattered file paths that look like

```
lolsed_bulsh.png
```

I want to prepend these file names with an extended path like:

```
/full/path/lolsed_bullsh.png
```

I'm having a hard time matching and capturing these. currently i'm trying variations of:

```
cat myfile.txt| sed s/\(.+\)\.png/\/full\/path\/\1/g | ack /full/path
```

I think sed has some regex or capture group behavior I'm not understanding

Comment: BRE doesn't support one or more `+`. Use `..*` instead (if you need to make sure there is at least 1 character).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`sed` uses POSIX BRE, and [BRE doesn't support one or more quantifier `+`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_03). The quantifier `+` is only [supported in POSIX ERE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_04_03). However, [POSIX sed uses BRE and has no option to switch to ERE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sed.html).

Use `..*` to simulate `.+` if you want to maintain portability.

Or if you can assume that the code is always run on GNU sed, you can use GNU extension `\+`. Alternatively, you can also use the GNU extension `-r` flag to switch to POSIX ERE. The `-E` flag in [higuaro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30431410/1400768) has been [tagged for inclusion in POSIX.1 Issue 8](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=528), and exists in [POSIX.1-202x Draft 1 (June 2020)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/607333/143394).

Comment: In GNU sed the `-r` invokes the `ERE` functionality however see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139126/whats-the-difference-between-sed-e-and-sed-e) for further details.

Answer (score 78):

In your regex change `+` with `*`:

```
sed -E "s/(.*)\.png/\/full\/path\/\1/g" <<< "lolsed_bulsh.png"
```

It prints:

```
/full/path/lolsed_bulsh
```

**NOTE:** The *non standard* `-E` option is to avoid escaping `(` and `)`

Comment: The detail I missed is that first capture group is on `\1`, NOT `\0`, which appears to be the whole current line.

Answer (score 30):

Save yourself some escaping by choosing a different separator (and `-E` option), for example:

```
cat myfile.txt | sed -E "s|(..*)\.png|/full/path/\1|g" | ack /full/path
```

> **Note** that where supported, the `-E` option ensures `(` and `)` don't need escaping.

Comment: Thank you! Used this to automate force cache busting of all css files (example):
`find . -type f -name "*.html" -exec sed -Ei "s|(css\/..*)\.css\"|\1\.css?v=$(date +%s)\"|g" {}`