# How to escape parenthesis in egrep

Tags: regex, bash, grep

You can escape parenthesis in `grep` by standard adding `\`.
But i want to escape parenthesis in `egrep` which uses `\(` as a grouping mechanism like `sed`.
I want to write `egrep` expression to parse the following:

`log_message(_sanitize("my string"));`

Comment: What is your search pattern?

Comment: You got it wrong: `grep` uses `\(...\)` for grouping, and `egrep` uses `(...)`.  Thus: `egrep 'log_message\(_sanitize\("my string"\)\)'`

Comment: This was helpful for me for regex with sed with capture groups: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30431410/470749

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parentheses in `grep` (BRE) require no escaping, they match themselves literally:

```
$ grep -o '(a)' <<< '(a)'
(a)
```

In `egrep` (ERE) parentheses are used for grouping. They can be escaped to match literal parentheses:

```
$ egrep -o '(a)' <<< '(a)'
a

$ egrep -o '\(a\)' <<< '(a)'
(a)
```

You can therefore just add escaping to yours to match the expression literally:

```
$ egrep -o 'log_message\(_sanitize\("my string"\)\);' \
    <<< 'log_message(_sanitize("my string"));'
log_message(_sanitize("my string"));
```

Comment: You have a typo error. The output of `grep -o '(a)' <<< '(a)'` should be `(a)`.

Comment: Copy-paste fail. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One way is to put the `(` in a character class like:

```
 egrep 'log_message[(]_sanitize[(]"my string"[)][)];' <file>
```