# Set/use a keyboard shortcut to replace a character in Visual Studio Code

Tags: replace, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

### What I want to know

- How to set a keyboard shortcut to replace `""` with `''`.
- Or is there a default shortcut to replace `""` with `''`?

### Purpose

I use Visual Studio Code on a Mac. I often replace `""` with `''`.

For example,

```
const foo = "foo";
const bar = "bar";
```

⬇️

```
const foo = 'foo';
const bar = 'bar';
```

I usually use Visual Studio Code's replace function with a regular expression like this.
[image: Replace VSCode]

I want to register a keyboard shortcut for this operation because I do it frequently.

### What I tried / Issue

I opened `keybindings.json` and tried to set a keyboard shortcut in it. But I have no idea what to write.

```
[
  {
    "key": "shift+cmd+'",
    "command": "actions.find" // ?????????
  }
]
```

What should I write in there? Or is there a default shortcut to replace `""` with `''`?

---

**Edit:**

According to Jeff Brower's answer (thank you!), `"args"` can be helpful for my purpose. I'm trying to change his/her code.

I wrote in `keybindings.json` like this but it doesn't work:

```
  {
    "key": "shift+cmd+'",
    "command": "editor.action.startFindReplaceAction",
    "args": {
      "query": "\"(.+)\"",
      "replace": "'$1'",
      "triggerSearch": true,
      "isRegex": true,
      "matchWholeWord": true,
      "isCaseSensitive": false
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think like `actions.find`, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/108459, that `editor.action.startFindReplaceAction` doesn't support arguments.

Comment: @Mark Thank you for the information. It's so helpful.

Answer (score 1):

According to the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57541328/perform-pre-defined-find-replace-all-in-vscode-using-a-keybinding), there is no built-in way to do this. However, I did get a similar keybinding to work. This searches all files in the workbench:

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+'",
    "command": "workbench.action.findInFiles",
    "args": {
        "query": "\"((?:\\\\[\"'\\\\bfnrt]|[^\\\\\"'\\n\\r])*)\"",
        "replace": "'$1'",
        "triggerSearch": true,
        "isRegex": true,
        "matchWholeWord": true,
        "isCaseSensitive": true
    }
}
```

The main caveat is that it doesn't automatically perform the replacement, but it does fill in the fields of the find and replace.

I also improved the regular expression a bit to handle javascript-style escaping, and allow empty strings ([unit tests](https://regex101.com/r/VkOM4h/1)). To use your original regular expression, replace the whole string with:

```json
"\"(.+)\""
```

Comment: Thank you for the JSON code :) That's the code I wanted. I'm trying to change it to suite my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with an extension, I'll show the code for that.  An extension allows you to set a keybinding if that is what you want.

But it is easy to accomplish what you want with these steps.

1. Select any `"`.
2. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to select all occurrences of `"`.
3. Type `'`.

---

The working part of the extension code:

```js
let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('yourExtensionName.someCommandName', async function () {

  const fileName = vscode.workspace.asRelativePath(vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.uri);

  vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.findInFiles',
    {
      query: "\"(.+)\"",
      replace: "'$1'",
      triggerSearch: true,
      isRegex: true,
      filesToInclude: fileName
      // preserveCase: true,
      // useExcludeSettingsAndIgnoreFiles: true,
      // isCaseSensitive: true,
      // matchWholeWord: true,
      // filesToExclude: "./*.css"
      }).then(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          vscode.commands.executeCommand('search.action.replaceAll');
        }, 1000);
      });
});

context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
```

Demo:

[image: find in file]

The extension works with the `findInFiles` command, since `actions.find` will not take arguments.  But it is restricted to the current file.  It finds the current fileName:

```
const fileName = vscode.workspace.asRelativePath(vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.uri);
```

and uses that in the `filesToInclude` argument.

Comment: Thank you for the tips :) That extension looks neat. I'll try it. I'm laughing myself. You're right. I don't need to use regex to replace `"` with `'`.