# Escape multiple dots in variable

Tags: bash

Suppose i have a variable  `$email` whose value is `stack.over@gmail.com`.I want to add a `\` before **every** **dot** **except the last dot** and store it in a new variable `$email_soa`.

`$email_soa` should be  `stack\.over@gmail.com` in this case.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do that?

Comment: @JohnKugelman email with more than one dot in BIND zone file gives `bad name (check-names)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gawk`:

```
var="stack.over@gmail.com"
gawk -F'.' '{OFS="\\.";a=$NF;NF--;print $0"."a}' <<< "$var"
```

Output:

```
stack\.over@gmail.com
```

Explanation:

- `-F'.'` splits the string by dots
- `OFS="\\."` sets the output field separator to `\.`
- `a=$NF` saves the portion after the last dot in a variable 'a'. `NF` is the number of fields.
- `NF--` decrements the field count which would effectively remove the last field. This also tells `awk` to reassemble the record using the `OFS` This feature does at least work with GNU's `gawk`.
- `print $0"."a` prints the reassmbled record along with a dot and the value of `a`

Comment: As far as I remember, decrementing `NF` isn't guaranteed to remove the last field in all versions of awk.

Comment: @TomFenech I've tried `busybox awk` which I have by the hand atm. It supports it as well.

Comment: @TomFenech POSIX doesn't say anything about assigning to `NF`, meaning you are right, it is not guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 4):

```
sed -E 's/\./\\\./g;s/(.*)\\\./\1\./'
```

should do it.

**Test**

```
$ var="stack.over@flow.com"
$ echo $var | sed -E 's/\./\\\./g;s/(.*)\\\./\1./'
stack\.over@flow.com
$ var="stack.over@flow.com."
$ echo $var | sed -E 's/\./\\\./g;s/(.*)\\\./\1./'
stack\.over@flow\.com.
```

**Note**

The `\\` makes a literal backslash and `\.` makes a literal dot

Comment: The `.` in the replacement part doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: Always nice to see a well phrased sed command. If you are really worried about portability, though, the `-E` for extended regular expressions is not supported in POSIX 7 (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html). I am sure you will have no problems in the real world, though.

Comment: @DrK : If I'm really worried about portability then I would replace the `-E` and escape the parenthesis. Also have a look at [\[ this \]](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3139925/1620779) . `-E` would work fine on most of the unices including Macs.

Answer (score 2):

You could use perl to do this:

```
perl -pe 's/\.(?=.*\.)/\\./g' <<<'stack.over@gmail.com'
```

Add a slash before any dots that have a dot somewhere after them in the string.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
temp=${email%.*}
email_soa=${temp/./\\.}.${email##*.}
```

Comment: Nice. but this is not a portable solution imho.

Comment: I am curious, why do you not think this is portable? The question was tagged with `bash` so do you mean across different versions of bash?

Comment: yes, kindly have a look at the [\[ changelog \]](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashchanges)

Comment: Fair enough. I guess it does have to be bash 3.2 or higher. So anyone a bit more than a decade behind on their updates might run into problems.