# Where am I making a mistake in substracting in sed?

Tags: json, bash, sed

I have a string:

```
{"testExecIssue":{"id":"1234","key":"KEY-6548","self":"site.com/rest/api/2/issue/68795"},"testIssues":{"success":[{"id":"465644","key":"KEY-6555","self":"site.com/rest/api/2/issue/68799"}]}}
```

I am trying to get "key" of "success", and I want sed to output just `KEY-6555`.

```
echo "{"testExecIssue":{"id":"1234","key":"KEY-6548","self":"site.com/rest/api/2/issue/68795"},"testIssues":{"success":[{"id":"465644","key":"KEY-6555","self":"site.com/rest/api/2/issue/68799"}]}}" > file
sed -e 's/.*testIssues":{"success":[{"id":"[0-9]","key":"\(KEY-[0-9]\).*/\1/' file
```

running sed outputs original echo, with [0-9] filled in:

```
{testExecIssue:{id:1234,key:KEY-6548,self:site.com/rest/api/2/issue/68795},testIssues:{success:[{id:465644,key:KEY-6555,self:site.com/rest/api/2/issue/68799}]}}
```

Now, I am either extremely dumb and outputting file, or using .* .* wrong. Where am I making a mistake and how should I correct it?

Comment: the current sed isn't matching nothing and so changing nothing, hence the same input line. try to quote `echo` with single quotes, the current one is removing all the double quotes inside; change also `[0-9]` to `[0-9]\+` or you'd match just one char.

Comment: Have you considered using `jq` for this job? `jq -r '.testExecIssue.key' <file.json` is much shorter code.

Comment: ...and not just shorter, but more reliable. A lot of JSON encoders don't guarantee key order -- it can just fall out of what order strings hash into -- so you don't know that `id` will always come before `key`. Similarly, the producer changes their settings so there's whitespace in your string, and the sed code fails then too. Use `jq` or another JSON-aware tool and those things aren't problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using [0-9] in you sed syntax, you will need to use sed -E and so:

```
sed -En 's/(^.*testIssues":\{"success":\[\{"id":"[0-9]+","key":")(KEY-[0-9]+)(.*$)/\2/p' file
```

You are matching potentially more than one digit after KEY and so use [0-9]+. Also ensure that you are escaping and {} [] characters.

We split the field into 3 sections designated by the three statements enclosed in () in the sed statement. We then print only the second section specified as specified with \2

Comment: Bracket expressions like `[0-9]` don't require using extended regular expressions.

Comment: @Amessihel -r and -E do the same thing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139126/whats-the-difference-between-sed-e-and-sed-e

Comment: @RamanSailopal, oh okay, it's not documented. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For JSON use a proper JSON parser like [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). jq has a full fledged query language that lets you easily find the data you need:

```
$ jq -r '.testIssues.success[].key' < file.json
KEY-6555
```

As [Charles Duffy says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64246390/where-am-i-making-a-mistake-in-substracting-in-sed/64247346#comment113608812_64246390), jq is not just shorter, but more reliable. A lot of JSON encoders don't guarantee key order -- it can just fall out of what order strings hash into -- so you don't know that id will always come before key. Similarly, the producer changes their settings so there's whitespace in your string, and the sed code fails then too. Use jq or another JSON-aware tool and those things aren't problems.