# How to remove trailing whitespaces with sed?

Tags: sed, whitespace

I have a simple shell script that removes trailing whitespace from a file. Is there any way to make this script more compact (without creating a temporary file)?

```
sed 's/[ \t]*$//' $1 > $1__.tmp
cat $1__.tmp > $1
rm $1__.tmp
```

Comment: You can use `mv` instead of `cat` and `rm`. Why are you using `cat` like that anyway? Why not use `cp`?

Comment: I used the knowledge I learned from this question to create [a shell script for recursively removing trailing whitespace](https://gist.github.com/dtuite/6314519).

Comment: Your solution is actually better when using MinGW due to a bug in sed on Windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313318/permission-denied-when-sed-in-place-edit-in-mingw

Comment: See also: [How to remove trailing whitespaces for multiple files?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10711051/562769)

Comment: Note that using `cat` to overwrite the original file rather than `mv` will actually replace the data in the original file (ie, it will not break hard links).  Using `sed -i` as proposed in many solutions will not do that. IOW, just keep doing what you're doing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Thanks to codaddict for suggesting the `-i` option.

The following command solves the problem on Snow Leopard

```
sed -i '' -e's/[ \t]*$//' "$1"
```

Comment: i found this here, http://joemaller.com/823/quick-note-about-seds-edit-in-place-option/

Comment: Like @acrollet says, you cannot use `\t` with sed other than GNU sed and it gets interpreted as a literal letter `t`. The command only appears to work, probably because there are no TAB's in the trailing whitespace nor a `t` at the end of a sentence in your file. Using `''` without specifying a backup suffix is not recommended.

Comment: If the resolution is indicated for Snow Leopard only, maybe the question should be 'how to remove trailing whitespace on Macos????'

Answer (score 208):

You can use the in place option `-i` of `sed` for Linux and Unix:

```
sed -i 's/[ \t]*$//' "$1"
```

Be aware the expression will delete trailing `t`'s on OSX (you can use `gsed` to avoid this problem). It may delete them on BSD too.

If you don't have gsed, here is the correct (but hard-to-read) sed syntax on OSX:

```
sed -i '' -E 's/[ '$'\t'']+$//' "$1"
```

Three single-quoted strings ultimately become concatenated into a single argument/expression. There is no concatenation operator in bash, you just place strings one after the other with no space in between.

The `$'\t'` resolves as a literal tab-character in bash (using [ANSI-C quoting](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings)), so the tab is correctly concatenated into the expression.

Comment: I get the following on my machine which I cannot update: 
`sed: Not a recognized flag: i`

Comment: This will also muck with line endings on Windows for some reason. Use caution.

Comment: hm. its also buggy in the sense that it will remove all trailing "t"s :)

Comment: "sed: Not a recognized flag: i –" This happens on OSX. You need to add an extension for the backup file after -i on Macs. e.g.: sed -i .bak 's/[ \t]*$//' $1

Comment: @GoodPerson If you were't kidding, you likely forget to escape the `t` :) `\t` is a tab, for those who may not already know.

Comment: @SeanAllred was not kidding: its utterly broken unless you happen to be using GNU sed (which is broken in so many other ways)

Comment: sed -i 's/[ \t]+$//' "$1" to ensure that there is present at least one whitespace...

Comment: The OS X version works for me. And as a bonus, it also adds a newline to the end of files that are missing one at the end!

Comment: Just so that others know (because there's "too many pending edits on SO" right now and I can't add this to the answer), you'll have to replace `$1` with the filename of your file, in order to use these.

Answer (score 71):

At least on Mountain Lion, Viktor's answer will also remove the character 't' when it is at the end of a line. The following fixes that issue:

```
sed -i '' -e's/[[:space:]]*$//' "$1"
```

Comment: My sed also wanted a `-E` indicating "extended (modern) regular expressions"

Comment: codaddict's answer has the same problem on OS X (now macOS). This is the only solution on this platform.

Comment: @JaredBeck Mine `sed` on El Capitan didn't.

Comment: thx! so to trim: `|sed -r -e 's"^[[:space:]]*""' -e 's"[[:space:]]*$""'`"`

Answer (score 14):

It is best to also quote $1:

```
sed -i.bak 's/[[:blank:]]*$//' "$1"
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var1="\t\t Test String trimming   "
echo $var1
Var2=$(echo "${var1}" | sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//;s/[[:space:]]*$//')
echo $Var2
```

Comment: Hey, that's just what I needed! The other sed solutions posted had issue integrating with a piped (and piped and piped...) variable assignment in my bash script, but yours worked out of the box.

Answer (score 5):

I have a script in my .bashrc that works under OSX and Linux (bash only !)

```bash
function trim_trailing_space() {
  if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "$FUNCNAME will trim (in place) trailing spaces in the given file (remove unwanted spaces at end of lines)"
    echo "Usage :"
    echo "$FUNCNAME file"
    return
  fi
  local file=$1
  unamestr=$(uname)
  if [[ $unamestr == 'Darwin' ]]; then
    #specific case for Mac OSX
    sed -E -i ''  's/[[:space:]]*$//' $file
  else
    sed -i  's/[[:space:]]*$//' $file
  fi
}
```

to which I add:

```bash
SRC_FILES_EXTENSIONS="js|ts|cpp|c|h|hpp|php|py|sh|cs|sql|json|ini|xml|conf"

function find_source_files() {
  if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "$FUNCNAME will list sources files (having extensions $SRC_FILES_EXTENSIONS)"
    echo "Usage :"
    echo "$FUNCNAME folder"
    return
  fi
  local folder=$1

  unamestr=$(uname)
  if [[ $unamestr == 'Darwin' ]]; then
    #specific case for Mac OSX
    find -E $folder -iregex '.*\.('$SRC_FILES_EXTENSIONS')'
  else
    #Rhahhh, lovely
    local extensions_escaped=$(echo $SRC_FILES_EXTENSIONS | sed s/\|/\\\\\|/g)
    #echo "extensions_escaped:$extensions_escaped"
    find $folder -iregex '.*\.\('$extensions_escaped'\)$'
  fi
}

function trim_trailing_space_all_source_files() {
  for f in $(find_source_files .); do trim_trailing_space $f;done
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For those who look for efficiency (many files to process, or huge files), using the `+` repetition operator instead of `*` makes the command more than twice faster.

With GNU sed:

```
sed -Ei 's/[ \t]+$//' "$1"
sed -i 's/[ \t]\+$//' "$1"   # The same without extended regex
```

I also quickly benchmarked something else: using `[ \t]` instead of `[[:space:]]` also significantly speeds up the process (GNU sed v4.4):

```
sed -Ei 's/[ \t]+$//' "$1"

real    0m0,335s
user    0m0,133s
sys 0m0,193s

sed -Ei 's/[[:space:]]+$//' "$1"

real    0m0,838s
user    0m0,630s
sys 0m0,207s

sed -Ei 's/[ \t]*$//' "$1"

real    0m0,882s
user    0m0,657s
sys 0m0,227s

sed -Ei 's/[[:space:]]*$//' "$1"

real    0m1,711s
user    0m1,423s
sys 0m0,283s
```

Answer (score 2):

In the specific case of `sed`, the `-i` option that others have already mentioned  is far and away the simplest and sanest one.

In the more general case, `sponge`, from the `moreutils` collection, does exactly what you want: it lets you replace a file with the result of processing it, in a way specifically designed to keep the processing step from tripping over itself by overwriting the very file it's working on. To quote the `sponge` man page:

> sponge reads standard input and writes it out to the specified file. Unlike a shell redirect, sponge soaks up all its input before writing the output file. This allows constructing pipelines that read from and write to the same file.

https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/

Answer (score 2):

To remove trailing whitespace for all files in the current directory, I use

```sh
ls | xargs sed -i 's/[ \t]*$//'
```

Comment: This won't work for BSD sed: `echo test | sed 's/[ \t]*$//'` gets truncated to `tes`.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=$1

if [[ -z $FILE ]]; then
   echo "You must pass a filename -- exiting" >&2
   exit 1
fi

if [[ ! -f $FILE ]]; then
   echo "There is not file '$FILE' here -- exiting" >&2
   exit 1
fi

BEFORE=`wc -c "$FILE" | cut --delimiter=' ' --fields=1`

# >>>>>>>>>>
sed -i.bak -e's/[ \t]*$//' "$FILE"
# <<<<<<<<<<

AFTER=`wc -c "$FILE" | cut --delimiter=' ' --fields=1`

if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
   echo "Some error occurred" >&2
else
   echo "Filtered '$FILE' from $BEFORE characters to $AFTER characters"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

These answers confused me.  Both of these `sed` commands worked for me on a Java source file:

- `sed 's/\s\+$/ filename`
- `sed 's/[[:space:]]\+$// filename`

for test purposes, I used:

```
 $ echo "  abc       " | sed 's/\s\+$/-xx/'
abc-xx
 $ echo -e "  abc   \t\t    " | sed 's/\s\+$/-xx/'
abc-xx
```

Replacing all trailing whitespace with "`-xx`".

@Viktor wishes to avoid a temporay file, personally I would only use the `-i` => in-place with a back-up suffix.  At least until I know the command works.

Sorry, I just found the existing responses a little *oblique*.  `sed` is straightforward tool.  It is easier to approach it in a straightforward way 90% of the time.  Or perhaps I missed something, happy to corrected there.

Answer (score -1):

To only strip whitespaces (in my case spaces and tabs) from lines with at least one non-whitespace character (this way empty indented lines are not touched):

```sh
sed -i -r 's/([^ \t]+)[ \t]+$/\1/' "$file"
```