# How to delete the last space at the end of each line in a text file? (shell scripts)

Tags: shell, trim

I have a file like this:

```
z E l f
A l t E^ t 
d Y s
m u s t
z E l f s
x @ w e s t
s t e t s
h E p
w i
t E n
o G @
o G @ n
m I s x i n
s t O n t
```

and I need to remove a space at the end of each line.

How can I do it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [removing trailing whitespace with sed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438306/removing-trailing-whitespace-with-sed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to delete trailing spaces and tabs from the end of each line.

```
awk '{ sub(/[ \t]+$/, ""); print }' file
```