# How can I remove the blank spaces in the last column in shell

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file with this strings

```
select chrom,chromStart,chromEnd,name from snp147 where name="rs12414460      ";
select chrom,chromStart,chromEnd,name from snp147 where name="rs12456              ";
select chrom,chromStart,chromEnd,name from snp147 where name="rs12434212334               ";
```

I want to delete the spaces in the `name` field.

How can I obtain this:

```
select chrom,chromStart,chromEnd,name from snp147 where name="rs12414460";
select chrom,chromStart,chromEnd,name from snp147 where name="rs12456";
select chrom,chromStart,chromEnd,name from snp147 where name="rs1243421111111";
```

Please Help me

I tried: `cut test.txt | cut -d ' ' -f1,2,3,4,5,6` but it doesn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove trailing whitespaces with sed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438306/how-to-remove-trailing-whitespaces-with-sed)

Comment: Define "column".  Try to provide a robust definition such that the last column of your sample input is not the string `";`

Answer (score 2):

This is more a job for `sed` than for bash.

```
sed 's/ *";/";/' test.txt
```

or (as a demonstration with a here-document):

```
sed 's/ *";/";/'  <<EOF
> select chrom,chromStart,chromEnd,name from snp147 where name="rs12414460      ";
> select chrom,chromStart,chromEnd,name from snp147 where name="rs12456              ";
> select chrom,chromStart,chromEnd,name from snp147 where name="rs12434212334               ";
> EOF
select chrom,chromStart,chromEnd,name from snp147 where name="rs12414460";
select chrom,chromStart,chromEnd,name from snp147 where name="rs12456";
select chrom,chromStart,chromEnd,name from snp147 where name="rs12434212334";
```

Comment: Should work, but it only prints the changes to your sceen and does not actually change the contents of the file. If you want it to actually change the file, then use the -i flag with sed: `sed -i ...`

Comment: Yea I know it but it doesn't change nothing in the same way :(