# How to remove trailing whitespaces for multiple files?

Tags: shell, find, whitespace, removing-whitespace, in-place

Are there any tools / UNIX single liners which would remove trailing whitespaces for multiple files **in-place**.

E.g. one that could be used in the conjunction with *find*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove trailing whitespace of all files recursively?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149057/how-to-remove-trailing-whitespace-of-all-files-recursively)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove trailing whitespaces with sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4438306/608639)

Answer (score 160, accepted):

You want

```
sed --in-place 's/[[:space:]]\+$//' file
```

That will delete *all* POSIX standard defined whitespace characters, including vertical tab and form feed.  Also, it will only do a replacement if the trailing whitespace actually exists, unlike the other answers that use the zero or more matcher (`*`).

`--in-place` is simply the long form of `-i`.  I prefer to use the long form in scripts because it tends to be more illustrative of what the flag actually does.

It can be easily integrated with `find` like so:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sed --in-place 's/[[:space:]]\+$//' {} \+
```

#### If you're on a Mac

As pointed out in the comments, the above doesn't work if you don't have gnu tools installed. If that's the case, you can use the following:

```
find . -iname '*.txt' -type f -exec sed -i '' 's/[[:space:]]\{1,\}$//' {} \+
```

Comment: By the way what's the thing with \+ as find exec terminator?

Comment: There are two variants of the `find -exec command`.  The first ends with `;`.  It runs `command` once for every file `find` returns.  The second ends with `+`.  It runs `command` as few times as possible by building up a list of files to run `command` on.  Since the `;` variant *requires* a backslash to escape the `;`, I also generally put it on the `+` as well (though I don't think it's strictly necessary for the `+`).

Comment: Talking about readability (and it's all a matter of taste) but I never use `-exec` with `find` because all that `{}+` stuff is like line noise. I prefer `find . -type f -name '*.txt' | xargs --replace=FILE sed --in-place 's/foo/baz/' FILE` but YMMV :)

Comment: It looks like this also converts DOS-style line endings to Unix-style.

Comment: It looks like this also messes file permissions on windows (running from git bash); also the \+ variant doesn't work.

Comment: On MacOS X, the stock `sed` does not support long options. I was able to get this recipe working by installing GNU sed with Homebrew (`brew install gnu-sed`).

Comment: On MacOSX, the stock `sed` will work with the following tweaks `find . -type f -name '*.rb' -exec sed -i ''  's/[[:space:]]*$//' {} \+`.   Note the `-i ''` and that we've replaced the `+` with `*`.

Answer (score 15):

Unlike other solutions which all require GNU sed, this one should work on any Unix system implementing POSIX standard commands.

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec sh -c 'for i;do sed 's/[[:space:]]*$//' "$i">/tmp/.$$ && mv /tmp/.$$ "$i";done' arg0 {} +
```

Edit: this slightly modified version preserves the files permissions:

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec sh -c 'for i;do sed 's/[[:space:]]*$//' "$i">/tmp/.$$ && cat /tmp/.$$ > "$i";done' arg0 {} +
```

Comment: This works almost perfect. The only thing is that it changes files permissions to (the default?) 100644.

Comment: Works flawlessly on BSD!

Comment: Very helpful on HP-UX.

Answer (score 4):

I've been using [this](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/b1e40e291372767a1b34ef36ed06ae0909a6b88d/.bash_history#L1364) to fix whitespace:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' -u 9
do
    if [[ "$(file -bs --mime-type -- "$REPLY")" = text/* ]]
    then
        sed -i -e 's/[ \t]\+\(\r\?\)$/\1/;$a\' -- "$REPLY"
    else
        echo "Skipping $REPLY" >&2
    fi
done 9< <(find . \( -type d -regex '^.*/\.\(git\|svn\|hg\)$' -prune -false \) -o -type f -print0)
```

Features:

- Keeps carriage returns (unlike `[:space:]`), so it works fine on Windows/DOS-style files.
- Only worries about "normal" whitespace - If you have vertical tabs or such in your files it's probably intentional (test code or raw data).
- Skips the .git and .svn VCS directories.
- Only modifies files which `file` thinks is a text file.
- Reports all paths which were skipped.
- Works with *any* filename.

Comment: Just to be on the safe side: you probably want to ignore all . files for automatic processing like this (Eclipse .metadata, .bzr, so on)

Comment: I regularly use dotfiles which should be cleaned up - .bashrc, .gitignore, etc. There's no authority on which files you should always exclude, so it's up to you and the task at hand.

Comment: the sed keeps carriage returns but appeats to eat newlines at the end of files :(

Comment: my bad, the sed adds a newline at EOF

Comment: I'm finding that `sed -i -e 's/[ \t]\+\(\r\?\)$/\1/'` (same sed wo. adding newline at EOF) isn't preserving DOS-style endings. Using gnu sed 4.8. Example `seq 2 | unix2dos | sed -e 's/[ \t]\+\(\r\?\)$/\1/' | xxd -p` outputs `310a320a` should be `310d0a320d0a`

Comment: with git for windows I had to add the `-b` option to `sed` to preserve `CLRF`. The regex preserved `CLRF` but `sed` didn't https://stackoverflow.com/a/11508669/1507124

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
sed -e -i 's/[ \t]*$//'
```

Btw, this is a handy site: http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt

Comment: -e on my version of sed is for adding a script, but you aren't specifying a script. I'm using GNU sed 4.7.

Answer (score 2):

#### `ex`

Try using [Ex editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_%28text_editor%29) (part of Vim):

```
$ ex +'bufdo!%s/\s\+$//e' -cxa *.*
```

<sup>Note: For recursion (bash4 & zsh), you can use [a new globbing option](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option) (`**/*.*`). Enable by `shopt -s globstar`.</sup>

#### `perl`

```
find . -type f -name "*.java" -exec perl -p -i -e "s/[ \t]$//g" {} \;
```

as per [Spring Framework Code Style](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Framework-Code-Style#indentation).

#### `sed`

For using `sed`, check: [How to remove trailing whitespaces with sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4438306/55075)

---

See also: [How to remove trailing whitespace of all files recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/149057/55075)

Comment: I think it is `"s/[ \t]+$//g"` in perl.

Answer (score 1):

For those that are not sed gurus (myself included) I have created a small script to use JavaScript regular expressions to replace text in files and does the replacement in place:

http://git.io/pofQnQ

To remove trailing whitespace you can use it as such:

```
$ node sed.js "/^[\t ]*$/gm" "" file
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the `sed` and `perl` commands did not work for me.
This did:

```
find ./ -type f | rename 's/ +$//g'
```

Feels like the most straight forward one to read as well.

Comment: Is this removing trailing spaces from filenames instead?