# Remove trailing blank lines in file in Bash by truncating

Tags: linux, bash

Is there a way to remove any trailing blank lines (lines that contain only whitespace) that are at the end of file using Bash?

For example, this:

```
123\n\n\n12\n  \n \t \n
```

Should become:

```
123\n\n\n12\n
```

I know how to do that in C, using fseek() and ftruncate(), but not sure if it's possible using bash and off-the-shelf cmd-line utilities, without creating a specialized C program for it.

I have seen some question asking about removing trailing whitespace in general, such as [How to remove trailing whitespace of all files recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149057/how-to-remove-trailing-whitespace-of-all-files-recursively), but I'm asking about doing it by truncating instead of overwriting the file (for performance reasons).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438306/removing-trailing-whitespace-with-sed

Comment: @IngoBürk: end of line != end of file

Comment: @Cyrus Yes, that's why I didn't post it as an aswer or marked it as a duplicate. I was just pointing out that similar questions have been asked. I could've made it clearer, maybe.

Comment: @IngoBürk Doesn't this overwrite the file? I specifically pointed out this as a difference in my question - it's about doing it by truncating instead of overwriting.

Comment: Any solution with standard tools you an just pipe the file contents instead of using the file, so if you don't want to write it to a file, you don't have to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find trailing blank lines with `tac` and then truncate with `dd`:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$1
trailing=$(tac "$file" | sed -n '/^[ \t]*$/!q; p' | wc -c)
end=$(( $(wc -c < "$file") - trailing ))
dd bs=1 seek=$end count=0 of="$file"
```

Comment: @sashoalm Your question was about bash and this is bash code. It doesn't work in `sh`.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I renamed it to a.bash and it works now. This is the first time I've encountered a script that needs an actual .bash extension. I guess I've always used only simple scripts.

Comment: @sashoalm Your question said to truncate the final line terminator, which would mean it's not a canonical text file by UNIX standards. Line based tools differ in how they handle these non-canonical files.

Answer (score 0):

I like [@that other guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1899640/that-other-guy)'s answer very much.

But here's one other possibility that uses the fact that command substitutions remove trailing newlines, and doesn't read the file twice to compute the position where it should be trimmed.

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$1
tokeep=$(wc -c <<< "$(< "$file")") || exit $?
dd if=/dev/null of="$file" bs=1 seek=$tokeep
```

---

If you want to remove trailing *spaces* (i.e., newlines, spaces, tabs, etc.), use `tr` to replace whitespaces with newlines, so that the trailing ones will be discarded:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$1
tokeep=$(wc -c <<< "$(tr '[[:space:]]' '\n' < "$file")") || exit $?
dd if=/dev/null of="$file" bs=1 seek=$tokeep
```

This preserves a single trailing newline (because the here-string `<<<` adds a newline). If you want to trim this trailing newline (but really, you shouldn't!), replace `seek=$tokeep` by `seek=$((tokeep-1))` in the `dd` statement.

**Note.** The `[[:space:]]` character class is locale dependent. In the C and POSIX locale it corresponds to space, form-feed `\f`, newline `\n`, carriage return `\r`, horizontal tab `\t` and vertical tab `\v` (see `man 3 isspace`)<sup>1</sup>. You can craft your own set of characters too: if you only want to trim trailing newlines and tabs but preserves all the other spaces, use

```
tr '\t' '\n'
```

---

<sup>1</sup> this is good since they all are one byte long, but don't use if your locale has spaces that are longer than one byte (e.g., an unbreakable space `U+00A0` is UTF-8 encoded as two bytes `C2 A0`). If unsure what locale is in use, you should use your own characters in `tr`, e.g., `'\t '`, just to be sure they all are one byte long. If you also want to deal with two bytes characters, you should replace them with two newlines, using e.g., `sed`. Example with unbreakable space:

```
sed 's/'$'\ua0''/\n\n/g'
```

assuming you have a UTF-8 locale. This is a bit clunky and maybe beyond the scope of your original question.