# How to remove trailing whitespace from file extensions with bash?

Tags: macos, bash, sed, osx-yosemite

I first tried everything at [How to remove trailing whitespace of all files recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149057/how-to-remove-trailing-whitespace-of-all-files-recursively) and  https://superuser.com/questions/402647/how-to-remove-trailing-whitespace-from-file-extensions-and-folders-snow , which did not work.

The file name for example is `"image.jpg                                                           "` and i want to convert it to `"image.jpg"`.

Please help, It also should be recursive. [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gm6yY.jpg)

Comment: Your example link seems to show a linefeed instead of a space. Could you   clarify how you are using the code from the previous articles? Maybe paste your code here..

Comment: For a single file whose path is in the variable `filepath`: `shopt -s extglob; local newpath; newpath=${filepath%%+([[:space:]])}; [[ $newpath != $filepath ]] && mv "$filepath" "$newpath"`. You should be able to generalize from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find . -depth ...` is the  best answer, but unfortunately it's unavailable to you (unless you install homebrew)

One difficulty of the `for` solution is that it does not descend into the directory hierarchy depth-first. So you're in danger of renaming a directory first, and then failing to rename any of the files under it.

To ensure that you're renaming files before any parent directory is to find the files and then reverse sort:

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob extglob
printf "%s\n" **/*[[:space:]] | sort -r | while IFS= read -r filename; do
    newname=${filename/%+([[:space:]])}
    mv "$filename" "$newname"
done
```

Comment: Why do you think `find` is unavailable on OS X? `find` is part of POSIX (the `-depth` primary is also POSIX — you don't need findutils for `-depth`), so `/usr/bin/find` should certainly be available on vanilla (without CLT, Xcode, or Homebrew). And your answer would break if there are linefeeds in filenames, which is precisely the case here.

Comment: Thanks Glenn Jackman, your code worked almost perfectly for the job it renamed all of the filenames with a linefeed but I still received an error "someCode.sh: line 1: shopt: globstar: invalid shell option name"; but i read that is because I need to upgrade bash.

Answer (score 1):

give this a shot.  (backup your data first)

```
find /tmp/ -depth -name "* *" -execdir rename 's/ /_/g' "{}" \;
```

replace /tmp/ with your folder.

for Apple, how about this:

```
for oldname in *
do
  newname=`echo $oldname | sed -e 's/ //g'`
  mv "$oldname" "$newname"
done
```

Comment: OS X doesn't have `rename`.

Comment: OS X is a UNIX, and actually more UNIX (so to speak) than any Linux since it's certified. `rename` is just less than nonstandard. By the way, your changed answer is still wrong.

Comment: I agree, however, rename is widely used in UNIX.  He tagged his question as UNIX, when he needed OSX.  Might be the same, but as in this example, the answer isn't.

Comment: look at that. it's a long week.

Comment: By the way, I don't know where you got the impression that `rename` is widely available. I just checked. No `rename` on OpenBSD; nor on Solaris. I'm sure the list can be much longer.

Comment: I tried your answer, but it didn't work it just renamed my directory names and when I put it in the same directory as the pictures it didn't do anything.

Comment: ok.  I'm going to go look around.  In the meantime, howabout this? http://mrrsoftware.com/namechanger/