# git - fatal: Unknown index entry format

Tags: git, github

When I'm trying use `git status` or `git checkout master` or `git pull`,

I'm getting an **error** :-

> "fatal: Unknown index entry format 61740000".

I've tried to Reinitialize existing Git repository. But it did not fix the problem.

I'm new to git, and I have just made a first branch and make some changes and trying to commit the changes.

Tried searching on Google but can't find the right solution for the code **61740000**.

Edit: Deleted the whole local repository and then again cloned from remote repository (git status worked), created a branch (git status worked) and made changes to files (git status error).

Please help.

Comment: It's worth noting that this error *should never happen*. If it is happening, that suggests there is something wrong with your computer, or your storage media (disk or USB drive or whatever), or your Git has a severe bug in it. It could potentially happen if you try to store your repository in a non-stable-storage area (e.g., a Dropbox folder) but in general you should see a *different* error for that.

Comment: It just happened to me with error `format 4e050000` instead of `61740000` when I run a search/replace accidentally including `.git`. Now I know I need to skip it and to run instead:  `find . -type d -name ".git" -prune -o -type f -exec your_script_here {} \;`

Comment: Just for google  "fatal: Unknown index entry format 14720000"

Answer (score 161, accepted):

When your index is broken you can normally delete the index file and reset it.

```
rm -f .git/index
git reset
```

or you clone the repo again.

Comment: Didn't help for me. My problem is git doesn't report ANY problem, IntelliJ reports it. Maybe I will try cloning the repo.

Comment: Works like a charm on `git version 2.21.0`

Comment: I have git for windows 2.28.0.windows.1 and this does not work for me. I wonder where `0x68690000` as an index entry is coming from.

Comment: Cloned Visual Studio, and got the same issue when trying to run `git status` with Cygwin's  git v2.31 (corrupted index).  Running these commands on a version of Git (2.17) for Windows through Git bash seems to recover everything, but not on Cygwin's. Cygwin's git doesn't seem to be compatible with VS or Git for Windows.

Comment: I thought that was enough at first, because it fixed `git status` and allowed me to commit stuff, but I then got other fatal errors during `git push` (“incorrect header check”, etc.), so I guess if you really messed up with your `.git/` you really need to exercise caution. Ended up backuping my changes, re-cloning the repo, and using `rsync` to bring back my changes.

Answer (score 16):

Regardless of the error code at the end of

```
fatal: Unknown index entry format
```

your git index file is corrupt. (I achieved this error after doing a find and replace for all files.)

If using a **Windows Command Prompt**,

```
del .git\index
```

will delete the index file and

```
git reset
```

will reset it.

[image: Windows Command Prompt]

Comment: This solves it for me using VS2019 on Win10. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue occured because I replaced line endings on the root folder of the repository, and that includes the `.git` folder:

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/\r//g' {} \;
```

I supposed to do that only within a specific folder.

I had to redownload the whole repository to fix the issue.