# git - fatal: unknown index entry format 0x632f0000

Tags: git, github, github-cli

When I'm trying use `git add .`

im getting a error:

*fatal: unknown index entry format 0x632f0000*

I have tried to reinitialize the file but I keep getting the same error.  Since I am new to git I am very overwhelmed by this whole push pull thing but I have the password/user/repo setup so I am unsure why it is not working.  I am on ubuntu trying to initialize my fork of litecoin.

Comment: I guess it's the same question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47109232/git-fatal-unknown-index-entry-format

Comment: If you're storing your Git repository in a cloud-synced folder, stop doing that. Otherwise, check for things that might corrupt files, such as bad RAM, failing disk drives, and so on.